# Email with attachment issue

Tags: email, google-apps-script, google-drive-api, email-attachments

I am a complete novice with this script, so I looked around and found some that meets my needs.  I am currently trying to automate the sending of a monthly newsletter and just  keep getting the following error:

Exception: Invalid argument: attachments (line 16, file "macros")

The code is as follows:

function sendEmails() {

```
var startRow = 1;
var numRows = 2;
var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 2)
var file = DriveApp.getFilesByName("Current Newsletter.pdf");
var data = dataRange.getValues();

for (i in data) {
   var row = data[i];
   var emailAddress = row[0];  // First column
   var message = "Dear "+ row[1] + "," + '\n\n' + "Please find attached, the latest update from [redacted].";
   var subject = "IAA Monthly Update";
   MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message, {attachments: [file]});
  }
}
```

Comment: the error is at line 16 but there is no line 16 ...update your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this one...

```
MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message, {attachments:[file.getAs(MimeType.PDF)] });
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation you cannot send emails with attachments when using MailApp. Instead, you need to use the GmailApp.

Below is an example of arrive at a solution using the GmailApp:

```
 // Send an email with a file from Google Drive attached as a PDF.
var file = DriveApp.getFileById('1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz');

GmailApp.sendEmail('mike@example.com', 'Attachment example', 'Please see the attached file.', {
    attachments: [file.getAs(MimeType.PDF)],
    name: 'Automatic Emailer Script'
});
```

- [MailApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app)
- [GrmailApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#sendemailrecipient,-subject,-body,-options)

Comment: Glad it works. Please place a checkmark on the answer so that this issue is resolved and  visible to others.